# Compile document without any in-text citations

Tags: bibtex, lyx, citing

Is there any way for me to easily and reversibly remove in-text citations from LaTeX output? I need to provide an accurate character count for my senior thesis that excludes citations (and figures and figure captions, but there are few enough of those that I'm willing to remove them by hand).

Right now I'm just exporting to plain text and running the result through `sed`, but this is not as nice as just being able to set a flag in the preamble or somesuch.

If it makes it any simpler (or harder!), I'm using LyX.

Comment: Do you still need to include the `bibliography`? You could just add `\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\unskip}` in your document preamble.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: In LyX, does Tools > Statistics do what you want? I don't think it counts references or citations.

Comment: @scottkosty, you are entirely correct. I don't know why I hadn't thought of that myself! If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Tools > Statistics`.

You can make a shortcut for this by going to `Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts` (the command name is just `statistics`).

I don't know if this function is well tested (I don't think it's used often). Please report any inconsistencies here or at [www.lyx.org/trac](http://www.lyx.org/trac).

Also not that when LyX 2.1 is released, you will be able to run

```
buffer-forall statistics
```

To get statistics (by document still) of all open documents.